# why the function only use the first element of array? (c++)

Tags: c++

I was trying to figure out a QuickSort algorithm.
But, it looks like I can't pass the array into Partition and QuickSort function. They only process the first element of the array.

How can I fix it?

```
template < class T > int getArrayLen(T & array) {
    return (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]));
}

int Partition(int a[], int first, int last) {
    int pivot = a[last];
    int i = first - 1;
    for (int j = first; j < last; j++) {
        if (a[j] <= pivot) {
            i++;
            swap(a[i], a[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(a[i + 1], a[last]);
    return i + 1;
}

void QuickSort(int a[], int first, int last) {
    int pivot;

    if (first < last) {
        pivot = Partition(a, first, last);
        QuickSort(a, first, pivot);
        QuickSort(a, pivot + 1, last);
    }
 }

 int main() {
    int a[] = {
         4, 32, 3, 13, 48, 45, 12, 54, 7, 42, 3, 12, 5, 24, 20
    };
    int length = getArrayLen(a);
    QuickSort(a, 0, length - 1);
}
```

Comment: @icepack why is that so? That is exactly a situation where the debugger is your best friend.

Comment: @icepack: bash.d is right. the OP is asking us to debug his code. he should do that himself.

Comment: @icepack: re your decay comment, you're wrong. the argument here is passed by reference. the implementation is unconventional and unsafe in general but it works for this usage.

Comment: @icepack well, I didn't get this straight, sorry. Yet that is a prime case for debugging.

Comment: Ok, some of us (including the 2 removed answers below) just jumped to conclusions here without dwelling into the question. I'm removing my comment, it's not related to decaying.

Comment: @icepack: Perhaps it's worth leaving some sort of comment. There may be people with <10k who will leap in suggesting that `getArrayLen` will return "the wrong value" without stopping to consider, compile or test.

Comment: @CharlesBailey if it's a gentle hint, I've already confessed my sins. BTW, the removed answers (not comments) weren't just from people with < 10k. Regarding leaving a comment, I think Cheersandhth's second comment covers it completely.

Comment: @icepack: No, there was no hint. I was just suggesting that for subsequent people arriving at this question, unless they have >10k, they might fall into the same trap if we remove all comments referencing `getArrayLen` and array pointer decay and template argument deduction.

Comment: We need people to test their own code. Given inputs: assert outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just decrease one from `pivot` before calling `QuickSort` again:

```
void QuickSort(int a[], int first, int last)
{
    int pivot;

    if (first < last)
    {
        pivot = Partition(a, first, last);
        QuickSort(a, first, pivot - 1);  // <--  HERE
        QuickSort(a, pivot + 1, last);
    }
}
```

And every thing is OK. Also test for various sizes of `a`: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...

Comment: Definitely not everything - see @WhozCraig's comment under the question

Comment: @icepack: I think he removed his comment. Anyway,  It's OK, questioner wrote the logic weird but it works fine. at the first `first = i - 1`, but then `i` will be increased (`i++`) otherwise `i+1` will be used.

Comment: Thank you! It works. I am a C++ beginner so sorry about the logic :(